# Adding option to select does not work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an option to select using the code below. But nothing changes on the actual page.

```
var x = document.getElementById("UserField");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Kiwi";
x.add(option);
console.log(document.getElementById("UserField"));
```

What I got from console.log is :

```
<select id="UserField" class="jqTransformHidden">
  <option value="">(choose one)</option>
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
  <option value="3">4</option>
  <option value="4">5</option>
  <option>Kiwi</option>
</select>
```

So the log contains Kiwi but when I open the page it's not there. What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Try `x.appendChild(option);`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: your code is working correctly .it is adding just wrap your code within window.onload

Comment: Seems to work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/obbfLfpk/

Comment: @nurdyguy It doesn't work...

Comment: If you see it in the console, than what is different from the code above? when/how is the option being added? Please show ALL your code.

Comment: The question then becomes, which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild:

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of
>   children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference
>   to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its
>   current position to the new position (there is no requirement to
>   remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other
>   node).

If you want to append something to any dom element, use `appendChild(theChild)` on the parent element. As Mike Brant pointed out `add(item, before)` should be okay too. (Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add)

**Answer:**

Make sure your script gets executed when the dom is ready (onload or DOMContentLoaded).

From https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload:

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

```
function load() {
  // execute your code here
}
window.addEventListener("load", load);
```

You can check this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pfc7fhkm/3/

Comment: It works fine as posted by the OP. Why would this change be necessary?

Comment: i dont know a standart `add` method for nodes. I only know appendChild as specified here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node

Comment: I would agree on perhaps using `appendChild()` as more uniform to other code, rather than the specific `add()` method which is only applicable to select elements through `HTMLSelectElement` interface.  `add()` does have additional functionality that, if used, could be reason to give preference to `add()`.

Comment: @MikeBrant thanks for the reference. this is actually something new to me. Never stop learning :D

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("UserField");
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = "Kiwi";
  x.add(option);
  console.log(document.getElementById("UserField"));
}
```

```html
<select id="UserField" class="jqTransformHidden">
  <option value="">(choose one)</option>
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
  <option value="3">4</option>
  <option value="4">5</option>

</select>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Id make it into a function but you can do it with a jQuery click as well

this will work if it is attached to a button's onclick function:

```
<script>
var mydropdown = $('#UserField');
function add(){
    mydropdown.append("<option>"+$(this).val()+"</option>");
}
</script>
```

this will work for on click as well

```
<script>
var mydropdown = $('#UserField');
var mybtn = $('#buttonId');
mybtn.click(function(){
     mydropdown.append("<option>+$(this).val()+"</option>");
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me when I place the script in the HEAD section. Kiwi shows up.  Where are you placing your java script?  I included full code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var x = document.getElementById("UserField");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = "Kiwi";
            x.add(option);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="UserField" class="jqTransformHidden">
  <option value="">(choose one)</option>
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
  <option value="3">4</option>
  <option value="4">5</option>
  <option>Kiwi</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try removing the JavaScript and see if it works.
If it does it probably means your JavaScript code has some errors, but for the html code I really don't see any error in it

Comment: Not really an answer.